# createFromFile( ) doesn't populate database - Room

Tags: android-room

**EDIT: 09/30**

Thanks to @shb, I've determined that createFromFile() is not properly populating the database as intended.

If anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong/missing, that would be great! Please refer to the below picture for reference on the database structure. Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

#### MainActivity

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var mDatabase: AppDatabase

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)
    }

    fun getFacilityNbr() {
        val planInfo = mDatabase.getPlanInfoDao().getPlanInfo()
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Size = ${planInfo.size}") // 0
    }

}
```

#### AppDatabase

```
@Database(entities = [PlanInfo::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    companion object {
        @Volatile private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        val file = File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/appdata/pla/assignment-file/test.db")
        Log.d("App Database", "Is valid file? - ${file.isFile}") // true

        fun getInstance(context Context) = instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "MyDb")
                .createFromFile(File("path/to/my/test.db"))
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build().also { instance = it }
    }

    abstract fun getPlanInfoDao(): PlanInfoDao

}
```

#### PlanInfoDao

```
@Dao
interface PlanInfoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo")
    fun getPlanInfo(): List<PlanInfo>
}
```

#### PlanInfo

```
@Entity
data class PlanInfo (
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Facility_Nbr")
    val facilityNbr: String
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo")
```

It returns a list of `PlanInfo`

Change return type to `List<PlanInfo>`

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo")
fun getPlanInfo(): List<PlanInfo>
```

Or you might wanna rewrite your query like below.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM PlanInfo where Lifecycle_ID= :lifeCycleId")
 fun getPlanInfo(lifeCycleId: String): PlanInfo
```

**EDIT**

In doubt, you make sure that there is data in that table, try inserting a row successfully before fetching in your code. Make sure its there.

Comment: The PlanInfo table is a special case in that it will only have 1 row, which is why I omitted the "Lifecycle_ID = :lifeCycleId" part

Comment: I changed the return type to List<PlanInfo> nonetheless to see if that helps at all, but the list I get back from the query is empty...

Comment: Could you make sure that there is data in that table, I saw that db explorer yet, try inserting a row successfully before fetching in your code. Make sure its there.

Comment: Inserting worked - in fact, now my code is working! It looks like somehow data is not being populated. In any case, this is a huge breakthrough. Thank you!

Comment: You helped me identify the problem, but the underlying issue (`createFromFile()` not working) is not resolved yet.